# How to fix "could not find function "%>%<-"

Tags: r, dplyr

I ran the script below before without any issue. But I now get this error message:
Error in animal_df %>% hamster_dt = data.frame("hamster", 2.879301) :
could not find function "%>%<-"

the content of the pet.csv file is the following:

| pet | length |
| --- | --- |
| cat | 30.869472 |
| dog | 50.729420 |
| bird | 6.113502 |
| mouse | 2.759222 |

I used the following code. I used to be able to add the species "hamster" to the table, to create a new column "size" with the rounded up length values, and to count the number of species for each size. (sorry for the silly example...)

```
#load package
library(dplyr)

#set work directory
setwd('C:/Users/...')

#import csv file
animal_df <- read.csv('pets.csv', header=TRUE, sep = ',')

#count number of species per size
animal_df %>%
  hamster_dt <- data.frame('hamster', 2.879301)
  names(hamster_dt) <- c('pet', 'length')
  all_pets <- bind_rows(animal_df, hamster_dt)%>%
    mutate(size = ceiling(length)) %>%
    str(all_pets)
    sp_per_size <- table(all_pets$size)
    
View(sp_per_size)
write.csv(sp_per_size, "C:/Users/.../sp_per_size.csv", row.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: `animal_df %>% hamster_dt <- data.frame('hamster', 2.879301)` is wrong. What do you intend to be doing there?

Comment: Does your script work as-is if you comment-out or delete the `animal_df %>%` line? The rest of it looks about right with that removed.

Comment: I was trying to add a new row to animal_df, by creating another data frame first and binding them together. When I delete `animal_df %>%` I get this message 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
Error in str.data.frame(., all_pets) : object 'all_pets' not found

Answer (score 0):

You have `%>%` strewn in two wrong places. We'll comment out the `animal_df %>%` and then remove the `%>%` between `mutate` and `str`.

```r
# since I don't have your data
# animal_df <- read.csv('pets.csv', header=TRUE, sep = ',')
animal_df <- data.frame(pet="cat", length=14)

#count number of species per size
# animal_df %>%
hamster_dt <- data.frame('hamster', 2.879301)
names(hamster_dt) <- c('pet', 'length')
all_pets <- bind_rows(animal_df, hamster_dt)%>%
  mutate(size = ceiling(length))
str(all_pets)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ pet   : chr  "cat" "hamster"
#  $ length: num  14 2.88
#  $ size  : num  14 3
sp_per_size <- table(all_pets$size)
```